# How Can I Add HTML Codes Inside Opening and Closing Shortcode?

Tags: php, html, shortcode

I need to add some codes inside the opening and closing shortcode. I have tried multiple way. The shortcode is

```
[hide for="logged"]Your Content Here[/hide]
```

I need to install this inside a page template. This is the code below that I am trying. Please correct me where I make mistake.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[hide for="logged"]');?>
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Domain</th>
        <th>Service Type</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Client Name</th>
        <th>Contact Email</th>
        <th>Contact Number</th>
        <th>Hosting Package</th>
        <th>Reseller Account</th>
        <th>Account Status</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>

        <?php
        global $post;
        $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 100, 'post_type'=> 'Domain_Hosting', 'product_cat' => 'Featured');
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>                        

            <?php $domain = get_field('domain'); ?>     
            <?php $service_types = get_field('service_type'); ?>    
            <?php $user_name = get_field('user_name'); ?>   
            <?php $client_name = get_field('client_name'); ?>   
            <?php $contact_number = get_field('contact_number'); ?>                               
            <?php $contact_email = get_field('contact_email'); ?>                                 
            <?php $hosting_package = get_field('hosting_package'); ?>                                 
            <?php $reseller_account = get_field('reseller_account'); ?>                               
            <?php $account_status = get_field('account_status'); ?>                               

      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $domain; ?></td>

        <td><?php $service_types = the_field('service_type'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $client_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $contact_number; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $contact_email; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $hosting_package; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $reseller_account; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $account_status; ?></td>
      </tr>


        <?php endforeach; ?>    
</table>
```

Comment: what are you actually asking?

Comment: What is correct way to add codes inside the opening and closing shortcode inside template.

[hide for="logged"]Can I add HTML and php Code Here?[/hide]

Comment: are you asking, if DOM element has class/id, hide/show?

Comment: I have this shortcode from the plugin. I want to add this shortcode in my page.php template. I want to wrap my codes using the shortcode. Generally we write the code <?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]');?>

But now the shortcode format is [shortcode] Some Codes Here [/shortcode], but this format only works with text. Not in page.php template. What can I do now?

Comment: Wait, is this wordpress?

Comment: yes, this is wordpress

Answer (score 0):

After html generated from shortcode, you should use jQuery to put your additional html.

[go to this reference](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to learn how to append html codes inside html element.

i.e add your table, class name = mytable

```
<table class="mytable">
```

And your shortcode generate some html tag, say div with class theshortcode

```
<div class="theshortcode">
```

Then append the html inside mytable class to theshortcode class.

```
$('.theshortcode').append($('.mytable').html());
```

Does it make sense to you?

Comment: I am not good atjQuery. However, I will try using your method.